# Traverse through an XML DOM in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery and trying to learn. But i am stuck with this problem.

I have the following response from a WCF Service.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">      
<s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <GetLabelDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetLabelDetailsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Rework"        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:ContainerDetails>
      <a:BarCodeStatus>4</a:BarCodeStatus>
      <a:BarCodeStatusDesc />
      <a:LabelGS1>011030310036099721336</a:LabelGS1>
      <a:LabelType>EA</a:LabelType>
      <a:NumberOfChildren>0</a:NumberOfChildren>
      <a:ParentGS1>012030310036099421511</a:ParentGS1>
      <a:ParentSerial>012030310036099421511</a:ParentSerial>
      <a:ParentType>CSE</a:ParentType>
      <a:ProductCode>R0010221130</a:ProductCode>
      <a:ProductDescription>R0010221130-H-688 MONOBUTYL ETHER</a:ProductDescription>
      <a:TypeName />
    </a:ContainerDetails>
  </GetLabelDetailsResult>
</GetLabelDetailsResponse>  </s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

I am trying to parse the value of BarCodeStatus tag. But i am lost as to how i can get this value.
 I have the following code in my web page. This shows the values of all the nodes, but when i try to find the BarCodeStatus node, i dont get anything (balnk value).

```
success: function (data) {
    $(data).find("GetLabelDetailsResponse").each(function () {
        alert($(this).find("GetLabelDetailsResult").text());
    });
}
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to how i can get the value of BarCodeStatus tag from teh response?

Thanks in Advance,
Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the colons in the [XML namespaces](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_namespaces.asp) (`a:` & `s:`).

### [Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/7H86B/1/)

```
var s = $('<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Header />  <s:Body>    <GetLabelDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">      <GetLabelDetailsResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Rework"        xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">        <a:ContainerDetails>      <a:BarCodeStatus>4</a:BarCodeStatus>      <a:BarCodeStatusDesc />      <a:LabelGS1>011030310036099721336</a:LabelGS1>      <a:LabelType>EA</a:LabelType>      <a:NumberOfChildren>0</a:NumberOfChildren>      <a:ParentGS1>012030310036099421511</a:ParentGS1>      <a:ParentSerial>012030310036099421511</a:ParentSerial>      <a:ParentType>CSE</a:ParentType>      <a:ProductCode>R0010221130</a:ProductCode> <a:ProductDescription>R0010221130-H-688 MONOBUTYL ETHER</a:ProductDescription><a:TypeName /></a:ContainerDetails></GetLabelDetailsResult></GetLabelDetailsResponse>  </s:Body></s:Envelope>');

//Find by the Ordinal positon 
s.find("GetLabelDetailsResponse").each(function () {
    alert($(this).find("GetLabelDetailsResult").children().children().eq(0).text());
});

//Escape the namespaces
s.find("GetLabelDetailsResponse").each(function () {
    alert($(this).find("GetLabelDetailsResult > a\\:ContainerDetails > a\\:BarCodeStatus").text());
});
​
```

If you need more comprehensive namespace support for jquery check out [XML Namespace Selectors for jQuery](http://www.rfk.id.au/blog/entry/xmlns-selectors-jquery/)